connect my gopro to my Raspberry pi (micropython)
I'm trying to sent commands to my gopro Hero 12 through my raspberry pi with micropython and the module aioble but i always receive this message via the GattError

Operation not permitted. Check characteristic properties and device
permissions.

The UUIDs came from the open_gopro api from gopro. My goal is to enable the ap mode on my gopro.
import uasyncio as asyncio
import aioble
import bluetooth
from micropython import const, schedule
GOPRO_SERVICE_UUID = bluetooth.UUID(0xFEA6)
GOPRO_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = bluetooth.UUID("b5f90072-aa8d-11e3-9046-0002a5d5c51b")
ap_mode_command = bytearray([0x03, 0x17, 0x01, 0x01])
async def enable_ap_mode():
    async with aioble.scan(5000, interval_us=30000, window_us=30000, active=True) as scanner:
        async for result in scanner:
            if GOPRO_SERVICE_UUID in result.services():
                device = result.device
                print("Found GoPro, attempting to connect...")
                try:
                    connection = await device.connect(timeout_ms=2000)
                    print("Connected to GoPro")
                    service = await connection.service(GOPRO_SERVICE_UUID)
                    characteristic = await service.characteristic(GOPRO_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)
                    await characteristic.write(ap_mode_command, response=True)
                    print("AP mode command sent")
                except aioble.GattError as e:
                    if e.args[0] == 5:
                        print("Operation not permitted. Check characteristic properties and device permissions.")
                    else:
                        print(f"Unexpected GATT error: {e}")
                finally:
                    await connection.disconnect()
                    print("Disconnected from GoPro")
                break

async def main():
    await enable_ap_mode()

asyncio.run(main())


Have you tried using a generic BLE exploration tool such as nRF Connect to see what operations the characteristic allows?

yes but i think its because it need to be paired

What happens when you try to pair?

I did my research and if I understand correctly, we cannot use the pairing function with raspberry pi.

It should work using bluetoothctl https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pairpipi.html#using-the-command-line

Your code gave me the following output on micropython-1.23.0:
MPY: soft reboot
Found GoPro, attempting to connect...
Connected to GoPro
Unexpected GATT error: 261
Disconnected from GoPro
I made few changes to make that code work, but you can continue working on it for your project. I have a Hero 8 which is not supported by OpenGoPro, but this code will turn the camera off with a command before disconnecting.
import uasyncio as asyncio
import aioble
import bluetooth
from micropython import const, schedule
from aioble.security import pair
GOPRO_SERVICE_UUID = bluetooth.UUID('0000fea6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb')
GOPRO_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = bluetooth.UUID("b5f90072-aa8d-11e3-9046-0002a5d5c51b")
ap_mode_command = bytearray([0x01, 0x05])
async def enable_ap_mode():
    async with aioble.scan(5000, interval_us=30000, window_us=30000, active=True) as scanner:
        async for result in scanner:
            if bluetooth.UUID(0xFEA6) in result.services():
                device = result.device
                print("Found GoPro, attempting to connect...")
                try:
                    connection = await device.connect(timeout_ms=2000)
                    print("Connected to GoPro")
                    await pair(connection)
                    service = await connection.service(GOPRO_SERVICE_UUID)
                    characteristic = await service.characteristic(GOPRO_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)
                    await characteristic.write(ap_mode_command, response=True)
                    print("AP mode command sent")
                except aioble.GattError as e:
                    if e.args[0] == 5:
                        print("Operation not permitted. Check characteristic properties and device permissions.")
                    else:
                        print(f"Unexpected GATT error: {e}")
                finally:
                    await connection.disconnect()
                    print("Disconnected from GoPro")
                break

async def main():
    await enable_ap_mode()

asyncio.run(main())


i found another solution but thanks
